# zurb Foundation Change Build Order

Tags: email, sass, zurb-ink

I'm using Zurb Foundation for Emails and noticing when I run Foundation watch, the inline style for Margin loads before margin. I'd like to reverse that.

I have tried to change the order of classes in my sass file, but I have not discovered a way to easily manipulate the load order to solve a bug issue in the way Outlook for Android handles html email.

Id like to have the end result be something like this:

`<table style="margin: 0; Margin: 10px;">`

Is there some documentation on this ?

Comment: 'Margin' will only work in Outlook. So whatever the order is it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Except that it does matter and does effect the output or I wouldn't be asking for any help reordering the automatic placement and moving it manually. If margin:0 loads after Margin: 10px, it has an effect and negates my fix, which helps center a button.